# Removing property with Json.NET using deep scan selector works with C# but throws ObjectNullReferenceException in F#

Tags: json, f#, json.net, jsonpath

Using json.net 12.0.3 in an netcoreapp3.1 application, the code works fine from if written in C# and will work using dot-notation in F# but as soon as I try to remove an element found by a deep scan selector in F# it throw an object null reference exception.  Given both are .NET languages my expectations would be for identical behavior.  I could not find any documented differences or behavior expectations.  Is there any possible resource other than not using F#?

**Sample Document**

```
{
  "Active": true,
    Nested: {
      "Active": true,
    }
}
```

**Failing F# Code**

```
let json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\example.json"))
json.SelectTokens("..Active") 
|> Seq.iter (fun n -> n.Parent.Remove())
```

**Succeeding C# Code**

```
var json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\example.json"));
json.SelectTokens("..Active").ToList().ForEach(i => i.Parent.Remove());
```

Comment: Have you tried converting to list like you do in C#?

Comment: The comment of @FyodorSoikin looks correct, try doing `json.SelectTokens("..Active") |> Seq.toList |> List.iter (fun n -> n.Parent.Remove())`.  Since `n.Parent.Remove()` modifies the `JToken` hierarchy you need to fully materialize the sequence before you can start to modify the query results.  If somehow that doesn't work please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the JSON that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Right you are.  I was too focused on the Json.net interaction and missed the more basic problem.    If you want to provide an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Done. (more characters because SO really doesn't want me to post short comments for some reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly where the NRE comes from, but there is one obvious difference between C# and F# versions: in C# you're converting to a list before iteration, but in F# you're not. Try doing that:

```
let json = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\example.json"))
json.SelectTokens("..Active") 
|> List.ofSeq
|> List.iter (fun n -> n.Parent.Remove())
```

I would speculate that as you call `Remove` the contents of the sequence changes, yielding a `null` somewhere. But if you convert to a list beforehand, it's a snapshot of the sequence as it was before any removals were done.

Comment: @FyodorSolkin Agreed that the NRE confused the issue.  I was expecting an InvalidOperationException wiith Collection with modified to have been thrown had the collection of JTokens not already been materialized.